# ffmpeg record video from image pipe with constant framerate

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, frame-rate

I'm trying to record a lossless video with ffmpeg, feeding it image data through standard input.

The process is started like this (C#):

```
string inputArgs = "-y -f image2pipe -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i -";
string outputArgs = "-r 20 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv422p -preset ultrafast C:\\temp\\out.mp4";

process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
        {
           FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
           Arguments = $"{inputArgs} {outputArgs}",
           UseShellExecute = false,
           CreateNoWindow = true,
           RedirectStandardInput = true
        }
};

process.Start();
```

The above works, but I have a problem with framerate. The rate I'm feeding images to ffmpeg is different over time, but I need ffmpeg to keep output rate constant. According to ffmpeg documentation, if set like this "-r 20" it should "duplicate or drop input frames to achieve constant output frame rate fps". But it doesn't. If I feed the images to the ffmpeg too slow, I'm getting fast playing video and vice versa.

Am I providing wrong arguments? Or it's somehow has to deal with ffmpeg getting images from Standard Input?

I tried these options in the output settings block: "vsync" (setting it to 1) and "fps_mode" (setting it to cfr). "vsync" doesn't have any effect, with "fps_mode" nothing works (video not recorded at all).

Comment: Images don't have timestamps, setting `-r 20` as input argument (before `-i`) assumes input framerate is constant 20fps. When `-r 20` applies the output (comes after the `-i`), FFmpeg assumes default input framerate of 25fps (and my drop or duplicate frames to match the desired 20fps of the output).

Comment: Right, but what if I have input images arriving at different pace - it might be from 10fps to 30fps, depending on the load of the system. Can ffpmeg handle it and output stable 20fps (by dropping and duplicating frames)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rotem that pointed to the fact that input frames come without timestamp, which prevents ffmpeg from keeping constant output framerate.

The solution is to use this option in the input block:

```
-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1
```

This tells ffmpeg to attach current timestamp to every received frame. People say it's not the most accurate solution, but definitely the easy one.